# How to fix the image to a div when it's height is greater than its width?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In Facebook, when we post any size images, it shows perfectly on the timeline. How do they do this?

I have tried following.

1. Setting the image as background of the div.
2. CSS - width: 100%; height:auto;

Both did not work, All over the stack overflow there is no option for this,finally decided to add this.

Comment: Asides from all the answers, facebook will also run all uploads through a server side script which will do the resizing and compression. They probably have their own in house code for doing this however you could use imagemagick to do the same thing, including sizing cropping uploads so as to always maintain the same width to height ratios (at least for thumbnails) http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parent `div` has *fixed dimensions* you can use CSS to **scale images while maintaining the aspect ratio** for both **landscape** and **portrait** photos.

The images will always fit inside the div.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Landscape</h1>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1600/800">
</div>
<h1>Portrait</h1>
<div class="container blue">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/800/1600">
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is Somewhat Ok, Not what Expected !

Comment: for the img we have to add margin:auto to automatically center the image if it is smaller than the div.

Answer (score 0):

At facebook they don't show images as backgrounds. Images are shown there using img tag. If you observe the height of facebook images may differ from each other but the width is always same. Try to post an extremely long image and you will understand the thing.

Solution:

```
<div>
    <img src="anysource">
</div>

<style>
   div{width: 480px;}
   div img{width: 100%; height: auto}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for the scaling technique.You should try to take the image and have it re-scaled i.e. change it's height and width using JavaScript DOM or CSS and re-uploading it to the page.

Your 1st solution did not work because images are not shown as the background of  rather shown with the .

Answer (score 0):

Asides from all the answers, stating about the css used on actual `<img>` tags.

Facebook will also run all uploads through a server side script which will do the resizing and compression.

They probably have their own in house code for doing this however you could use Imagemagick to do the same thing, including sizing and cropping uploads, so as to always maintain the same width to height ratios (at least for thumbnails).

Some examples can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

For a pure css option you could look into the background image property while utilising the positioning arguments.

Here's a snippet taken from w3cschools.

```
div {     
Width:100px;
Height:100px;
background-image:url('smiley.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:50% 50%;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp